# php MySql query `LIKE '$word'` returns NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, sql-like

In the code below the

```
var_dump($row);
```

shows `NULL`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM maintable WHERE Category LIKE '$word'
                                                        OR Title LIKE '$word'
                                                        OR Title2 LIKE '$word'
                                                        OR Description LIKE '$word'
                                                        OR Description2 LIKE '$word'
                                                        OR Preimushestva LIKE '$word'
                                                        OR Preimspisok LIKE '$word';";

            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query)
            or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($link));

            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            var_dump($row);
```

and `$word = 'dolor'`
and I have word dolor in my table, in Description tab help me find mistake please

Comment: "and I have word dolor in my table" --- clarify that. What exact value do you have?

Comment: Your script is probably [prone to SQL injections](http://bobby-tables.com). Consider using Prepared Statements.

Comment: @TimWolla: you cannot tell if it's **prone**. Please stop spreading your guesses as the truth. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, in Description column of my table there is text :
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing...
so the code was supposed to find this through query, as I understand, but it didnt

Comment: @user3182751 you need to change your query like John Conde have listed on his answer. Also make sure to use `$word = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['word']);` if you haven't to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: @zerkms I added a probably, no reason for being that rude.

Comment: @TimWolla: I didn't mean to be rude - it's just about being sick of over-panicked people around who refer to that site without any reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing your pattern matching characters. Without them `LIKE` is essentially the same as `=`.

Here's an example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM maintable WHERE Category LIKE '%$word%'
                                                    OR Title LIKE '%$word%'
                                                    OR Title2 LIKE '%$word%'
                                                    OR Description LIKE '%$word%'
                                                    OR Description2 LIKE '%$word%'
                                                    OR Preimushestva LIKE '%$word%'
                                                    OR Preimspisok LIKE '%$word%';";
```

Comment: +1 for actually explaining what you changed and why.

Comment: Oh thanks man, I didnt know that. Can someone please say to me how this thing is ccalled so I could read about it because its new to me.
I can mark this as answer in 9 minutes which i will do

Comment: Start here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Answer (score 4):

Look at this link : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM maintable
              WHERE Category LIKE '%".$word."%'
              OR Title LIKE '%".$word."%'
              OR Title2 LIKE '%".$word."%'
              OR Description LIKE '%".$word."%'
              OR Description2 LIKE '%".$word."%'
              OR Preimushestva LIKE '%".$word."%'
              OR Preimspisok LIKE '%".$word."%';";
```

Comment: This was the first possibly correct answer so it definitely doesn't deserve a downvote.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I downvoted because currently the answer doesn't actually *explain* anything, those `%` mean nothing to an unseasoned developer, and giving the OP code to copy and paste isn't going to put them on the right track at all.

Comment: @Marty: even if the answer doesn't explain it but is still correct and not harmful - it **makes no sense** to downvote it. +1d just because downvoting it in this case is silly.

Comment: @zerkms If that *is* the case then I'll retract it once I can... Perhaps I misunderstand the downvote mechanic as being a device to encourage improving an generally unhelpful answer.

Comment: @Marty: there is the third option - not voting. You aren't obliged to put your vote to every single answer. This answer isn't harmful. It's neutral. It solves the original issue. It doesn't teach the OP anything new indeed. But it doesn't make the community worse (or the overall SO quality lower).

Comment: @Marty You should read this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down "Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing."

Answer (score 1):

My best guess would be that you need to search for `'%dolor%'`.  The expression `like` without any wild card characters searches for an exact match.

However, it would help if you printed out the query *after* the variable substitution.  You can edit your question with this information if the wildcard form doesn't fix your problem.